# Create nested list with PHP from XML dataset

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xpath, simplexml

I'm trying to build an unordered list from an existing XML file which contains categories and subcategories + images. I need each subcategory to be an item in an unordered list with each related image in a nested list. The subcategories should be shown only once (must not repeat if it's the same). I believe what I'm looking for is a recursive loop, but that's where I get lost.

Essentially, I'm trying to achieve a look similar to this:

--------------DOGS-------------
    [..........small..........]
    [picture] [picture]
    [..........large..........]
        [picture]
--------------CATS-------------
    [..........medium..........]
    [picture]
    [..........large..........]
        [picture] [picture]

My XML file structure:

```
 <root>
    <animal>
        <category>DOGS</category>
        <subcategory>small</subcategory>
        <name>Terrier</name>
        <image>aaa.jpg</image>
    </animal>
    <animal>
        <category>-</category>
        <subcategory>small</subcategory>
        <name>Havanese</name>
        <image>bbb.jpg</image>
    </animal>
    <animal>
        <category>-</category>
        <subcategory>large</subcategory>
        <name>Dalmatian</name>
        <image>ccc.jpg</image>
    </animal>
    <animal>
        <category>CATS</category>
        <subcategory>medium</subcategory>
        <name>Abyssinian</name>
        <image>ddd.jpg</image>
    </animal>
    <animal>
        <category>-</category>
        <subcategory>large</subcategory>
        <name>Birman</name>
        <image>eee.jpg</image>
    </animal>
    <animal>
        <category>-</category>
        <subcategory>large</subcategory>
        <name>American Shorthair</name>
        <image>fff.jpg</image>
    </animal>
</root>
```

Here's what I have attempted so far:

```
    <?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

    $categories     = array();
    $subcategories = array();
    $names      = array();
    $image         = array();

    foreach($xml->animal as $animals) { 
        $category        = $animals->category;
        $subcategory     = $animals->subcategory;
        $name            = $animals->name;
        $image       = $animals->image;

        $categories[]     = $category;
        $subcategories[] = $subcategory;
        $names[]          = $name;
        $images[]        = $image
    }

    function getMenu($xml, $categories, $subcategories, $names, $images) {
        $output = '<ul>';
             foreach(array_keys($images) as $n) {       
                 $output .= '<li class="animals" data-tags="'.$names[$n].'">';
                 $output .= '<img src="xml/'.$images[$n].'" width="75" height="75" alt="'.$names[$n].'" />';
                 $output .= '</li>';    
             }

        $output.= '</ul>';  
        return array($output);  
    }

    $result = getMenu($xml, $categories, $subcategories, $names, $images);

    echo json_encode($result);

    ?>
```

Comment: EASY: get the data in json format then dont worry about using XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are literally a thousand ways how you can do that. Most straight forward is probably with `xpath()`. It's a powerful XML querying language worth to learn. Example with your `$xml` simplexmlelement:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//category[not(. = following::category)]') as $category) {
    echo "=== $category === \n";
    foreach ($xml->xpath("//animal[category = '$category']/subcategory[not(. = following::animal[category = '$category']/subcategory)]") as $subcategory) {
        echo "  = $subcategory =\n";
        foreach ($xml->xpath("//animal[category = '$category' and subcategory = '$subcategory']") as $animal) {
            echo "    * $animal->name ($animal->image)\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
=== DOGS === 
  = small =
    * Terrier (aaa.jpg)
    * Havanese (bbb.jpg)
  = large =
    * Dalmatian (ccc.jpg)
```

You further on might want to replace the lengthy xpath strings out there. With the help of a closure and an iterator aggregate, it's even possible to reduce the code quite comfortable to:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo "=== $category === \n";
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        echo "  = $subcategory =\n";
        foreach ($animals as $animal) {
            echo "    * $animal->name ($animal->image)\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow to change the XML structure later on and have the xpath's configured in a central location:

```
$categories    = $vpath('//category[not(. = following::category)]');
$subcategories = $vpath('//animal[category = "%1$s"]/subcategory[not(. = following::animal[category = "%1$s"]/subcategory)]', [&$category]);
$animals       = $vpath("//animal[category = '%s' and subcategory = '%s']", [&$category, &$subcategory]);
```

I have put that example online as a [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/w3e6PL).

I have the output just as text with indents, however thanks to the `foreach`s it should be really straight forward to turn that into HTML. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Would you mind looking at the updated XML in my original post? Thanks

Comment: Well you have moved many animals into the category `-`. You might want to structure your XML right ahead in a format that puts animals into subcategories and subcategories into categories. You then won't have that much hassle in querying the data with xpath.